# How to fill background color in cell based on the condition?

Tags: python, html, css

I have written one python script in which i am changing dataframe into html file.
Now i want to fill color in some particular cell based on some condition.

example:

```
Master Job Name     Status
Settlement          Success
Ix_rm_bridge        Failed
unit                Success
Test                Failed
```

I want to fill color in Failed cell.
i have tried one code for this but not able to fill color properly.
can you please help me?

code:

```
def send_mail(audit_df, attach_file):
    #audit_df = df1
    #print(audit_df)
    #attach_file = LOG_FILE
    try:
        FROM_ADDER = 'hadoop@ip-10-37-195-190.jnj.com'
        TO_ADDER = 'spate233@its.jnj.com'
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = FROM_ADDER
        msg['To'] = TO_ADDER
        #msg['Subject'] = ''
        #body = ''
        msg['Subject'] = "iMedical Refined Layer script Execution has been finished"
        body = " Hi Team, \n\n The iMedical Refined Layer Script has been finished. \n\n Thanks and Regards \n iMedical Team"
        if audit_df is not None:
            if audit_df['Status'].all() == 'Failed':
                audit_df.to_html('audit_file.htm', index=False)
                audit_data_body = open('audit_file.htm').read().replace('<th>','<th bgcolor="#B4C6E7">').replace('<td>', '<td bgcolor="#F2F2F2">').replace('<td>$Status</td>', 'tr bgcolor="#FF5733">')
                #print(audit_data_body)
                html = """
                <html><body>
                <p>Hi Team,</p>
                <p>iMedical Refined Layer job has finished.</p>
                <p>Please check the job status</p>
                <p style="color: red;"> """ + audit_data_body + """ </p> 
                <p>Thanks and Regards,</p>
                <p>iMedical Team</p>
                </body></html>
                """
                msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(html, 'html')])
                msg['From'] = FROM_ADDER
                msg['To'] = TO_ADDER
                msg['Subject'] = "Failed status for job run"
            else:
                audit_df.to_html('audit_file.htm', index=False)
                audit_data_body = open('audit_file.htm').read().replace('<th>','<th bgcolor="#B4C6E7">').replace('<td>', '<td bgcolor="#F2F2F2">')
                #print(audit_data_body)
                html = """
                <html><body>
                <p>Hi Team,</p>
                <p>iMedical Refined Layer job has finished.</p>
                <p>Please check the job status</p>
                <p style="color: red;"> """ + audit_data_body + """ </p> 
                <p>Thanks and Regards,</p>
                <p>iMedical Team</p>
                </body></html>
                """
                msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(html, 'html')])
                msg['From'] = FROM_ADDER
                msg['To'] = TO_ADDER
                msg['Subject'] = "Success status for job run"

        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        if attach_file is not None:
            attachment = MIMEApplication(open(attach_file, "rb").read(), _subtype="txt")
            attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attach_file)
            msg.attach(attachment)
        server = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(FROM_ADDER, TO_ADDER.split(','), text)
        server.quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried inline styles? For example:

`<td style='background-color: "red"'>Test</td>`

Comment: @AlejandroVicaria i want red color in status column when failed comes in.